# Get User_ID from interactions in DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm Currently Trying to get the user_id from the interaction.
This code will add command named 'test' that will give option 'testing' and when someone types '1' then it should show the channel_id that the command went from and also the user that did that command.

test.js :

```
module.exports = {
    name: "test",
    description: "example",
    options: [
        {
            name: "testing",
            description: "testing only.",
            type: 3,
            required: true,
        },
        
    ],
    async execute(_bot, say, interaction, args) {
        let object1 = args[0].value;
        if (object1 == '1') {
            await say(interaction, 'Channel ID : ' + interaction.channel_id +  '\nUser : '+ interaction.message.author.id);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        
    },
};
```

My Problem here that it's not getting the user.id in any way i have tried the following examples :

```
interaction.member.id;
interaction.user.id;
interaction.user_id;
interaction.member_id;
interaction.guildmember.id;
```

Noone of them works.

Comment: Have you tried to log the value of `interaction`? How do you call the `execute` method? Are you sure the order of the arguments is correct?

Comment: channel_id already works even other stuff does, it's just not getting the user id in anyway.

Comment: It does actually log the user id :  user: {
      username: 'JADA',
      public_flags: 4194304,
      id: '225043200430047233',

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to actually read the log for it, LMAO i feel stupid but thanks!

Comment: Great, I'm glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

It should've been ;

```
interaction.member.user.id
```

Because it appeared in the log under member.